# Sitefinity sf-html-field.sf-cshtml File

Tags: sitefinity

Question concerning the Bootstrap \ResourcePackages\Bootstrap4\client-components\fields\html-field\sf-html-field.sf-cshtml File.

If I modify this file (e.g. add a button), I would expect to those changes take effect on the HTML editor's toolbar when I go in to edit a record in a list with a field that's listed as rich text.  Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any changes.

Also tried modifications to the AdminApp\config.json but modifying THAT file also does nothing.

Is there an additional file required?

Comment: what version are you on? Also, does your page actually uses the Bootstrap4 package or a custom package that was copied from Bootstrap4 package?

Comment: Just to add to @VeselinVasilev - if you could share some code that will be helpful beyond pointing you to https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/extend-the-html-field-of-the-rich-text-editor where it guides you step by step on the csthml and js changes needed.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev - This is SF 14.0.  I have a bootstrap 4 folder under Resource Packages.  Is there anything else more I need to do to make sure I'm using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @jbokkers - responded ... it just needs like the file isn't used at all - even if i delete it there are no effects to the HTML editor on list editing screens on my custom content types.

Comment: the package   <package id="Telerik.Sitefinity.Feather" version="14.0.7721" targetFramework="net48" /> is present

Comment: These are questions on the backend user experience

Answer (score 0):

Backend for SF 14.0 is done via adminapp/config.json.  I had mistakenly had a comma in the filename:
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/120/administration-configure-the-kendo-editor

Backend for SF 14.4 is done slightly differently:
https://community.progress.com/s/article/after-upgrade-to-14-3-it-is-not-possible-to-use-config-json-to-customize-rich-text-editor